How to Resolve Errors When Running Python Jobs in Azure App Service WebJobs
I want to run a Python job in an Azure App Service WebJob.
The App Service plan is Basic.
The OS is Linux, and the runtime is Python. The deployment model is set to “Code.”
I created a WebJob by uploading a ZIP file containing a simple Python script.
However, when I run the WebJob, an error occurs.
Looking at the error logs, I see messages like the following:
[11/18/2024 23:23:22 > d7204e: SYS INFO] Status changed to Initializing
[11/18/2024 23:23:22 > d7204e: SYS INFO] Run script 'run.py' with script host - 'PythonScriptHost'
[11/18/2024 23:23:22 > d7204e: SYS INFO] Status changed to Running
[11/18/2024 23:23:22 > d7204e: ERR ] An error occurred trying to start process 'python.exe' with working directory '/tmp/jobs/triggered/webjobpy/bphw5fzr.pno/webjobtest'. No such file or directory

Looking at the error message, it says that python.exe cannot be found, and I suspect that might be the issue.
I have confirmed that the OS is set to Linux.
Is there any solution for this? Or is it that Python jobs are not supported in WebJobs?
I expected the Python job to run successfully since Python should be supported in WebJobs.

Use this #!/usr/bin/env python3 at top of the run.py.

Thank you.
I added #!/usr/bin/env python3 at the top of run.py and tried running it, but I’m still getting the same error.
I feel it’s strange that the OS is Linux, yet the error says, “start process with ‘python.exe’”.

Provide code what you have tried?

The error is related to your file name run.py, try to change it to a different name.


python
Run script 'run.py' with script host - 'PythonScriptHost'
[11/18/2024 23:23:22 > d7204e: SYS INFO] Status changed to Running
[11/18/2024 23:23:22 > d7204e: ERR ] An error occurred trying to start process 'python.exe' with working directory '/tmp/jobs/triggered/webjobpy/bphw5fzr.pno/webjobtest'. No such file or directory

Even I got same Error when I used run.py as the Python file name.
The WebJobs service treated run.py as the entry point but did not find any runnable scripts in the file, which caused an error.
I created a simple Python WebJob with a file name different from run.py.
webjob. py:
print("Hello, world!")

script. sh:
python3  run.py

WebJob Output:


Thank you. When I tried the sample you suggested, it worked. it seems the issue was caused by using a python file.

The error “python3 or pip3 command not found” occurs due to the passage of time or a reboot.
What is the cause of this?

Thanks for letting us know, we recently added support for WebJobs in Linux and it is in Preview at the moment.
We will make sure the 'PythonScriptHost' works well for GA.

Thank you for your response.
While I'm still facing issues with PythonHostScript, it seems that my Shell Script jobs also encounter errors after App Service restarts or over time. The error message indicates that 'pip3' and 'python3' cannot be found.
Could there be any missing configurations or environment variable settings in my App Service?
Since I've only conducted a basic test, no specific environment variables have been set up at this time.
